# getting table(column) to return 0 for non-represented values

Tags: r

I'm working with a data set where my outcome of interest is coded across multiple columns and takes on values of 1, 2 and 3. Running `table()` across any one of these columns sometimes gives me results of the following (desired) form:

```
1 2 3
8 87 500
```

But also, for example, sometimes gives me results that look like this, when there are no 2's in a column

```
1 3
5 200
```

This is a problem as I try to combine all of these tables using rbind, which I do using this code.

```
tables = sapply(.GlobalEnv, is.table)
allquestions <- do.call(rbind, mget(names(tables)[tables]))
```

When this code comes across tables of the latter form, it seems to treat values in the '3' column as though they were in the '2' column, because '3' is in the second position. it then seems to take the value for the '3' position from the 1 position, as shown below

```
1 2 3
8 87 500
5 200 5
```

What I want it to look like is this:

```
1 2 3
8 87 500
5 0 200
```

Is there any way to make table() look for values that might not be represented in a column? Ideally, I would want it to print out the following for the second table example I gave.

```
1 2 3
5 0 200
```

Alternatively, is there a way to make the way I use rbind function pay attention to column names and merge them appropriately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the values to factor with levels to specify all the values it can take.

```
x <- c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2)
table(x)
x
#1 2 3 
#2 2 1 

x <- c(1, 3, 3)
table(x)
#x
#1 3 
#1 2 

table(factor(x, 1:3))
#1 2 3 
#1 0 2
```